# dynamic associative array creation whith jquery and xml

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, associative

I'm trying to store data from a xml-file in a associative Array.
Creating the array works fine but I can't access the data in other functions (i.e. checkArray()).

```
var picSetsData = (function () {
    var _picSets = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/content.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            $(xml).find('set').each(function (i) {
                _picSets[i] = [];
                _picSets[i].fehler = [];
                _picSets[i].url = $(this).find('src').text();

                $(this).find('spot').each(function (e) {
                    _picSets[i].fehler[e] = [];
                    _picSets[i].fehler[e].x = $(this).find("x").text();
                    _picSets[i].fehler[e].y = $(this).find("y").text();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    return {
        getPicSets: function () {
            if (_picSets) return _picSets;
            else {
                console.log('error');
            }
        }
    };
})();

checkArray();

function checkArray() {
    console.log(picSetsData.getPicSets().length); // 1
    console.log(picSetsData.getPicSets()); // my Array Data
    console.log(picSetsData.getPicSets()[1]); //undefinded
    console.log(picSetsData.getPicSets()[1].url); //undefinded
}
```

Any ideas to solve this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` call is asynchronous, so the surrounding function will return long before the data for the array is sent by the server.

You can do your "checkArray()" work *inside* the "success" callback.

Comment: Your right. I put the checkArray() inside $(document).ready(function(){...}); and erverything works now

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `_picSets` as a **local variable** inside the function `picSetsData`. You need to declare it outside of the function if you want to make it a global variable that can be shared across functions.

Comment: Well he's trying to `return` it from the function that makes the ajax call, but of course that won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

There's no associative arrays there, just regular arrays.

Array indexes are zero based, so if you have one item in the array, it's at index zero:

```
console.log(picSetsData.getPicSets()[0]);
```